# how can i get the variable "a" to use it outside the try and catch?

Tags: java, scope

I am trying to retrive the total in the below query, how can i do it, since i want to put the result in a jTextField, the try/catch is inside a buton action performed

```
try {
  Connection conn = new Operaciones().conectarLogin();

  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  String sql = "RETURN total;"+
                "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cantidad_productos()"+
                "RETURNS integer AS $total$"+
                "declare total integer;"+
                "BEGIN SELECT count( *) into total FROM producto; END;"+
                "$total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;";

      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql); 
      int total = rs.getInt("total");
      String a = Integer.toString(total);
      jTextField1.setText(a);

}catch (SQLException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excepción de SQL: " + e);}
```

Comment: what happens when you execute this?  you should print any exceptions and update your question with them.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you should just be able to declare `a` before the `try`. Then it will still be in scope after you exit the `try{}` block. Also, this is really a Java question, not a PostgreSQL or NetBeans question.

Comment: Why? It doesn't have a value. Why would you want to use it outside the `try/catch`? If the connection or the query fails, or there are no results, you have nothing to update the text field *with.* Code that depends on the success of a `try` block should be inside the `try` block.